# Problem with bibliogrpahy

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, warnings, logging

I was working on my thesis and everything is fine and works as ist should.

[image]

Then I realized that this is written in the log file:
[image]

The document still works fine but I do not understand what it wants to tell me or what the actual problem is since I do  not remember changing anything.
Do I have to worry about that. What did I wrong?

I am using this `biblatex` package:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliogrpahy.bib}
```

Can anyone help me understanding the problem?

Comment: The `biblatex` warning about the BIbTeX backend will always (well at least for a few years) have been there. And it means pretty much what it says: You are using BibTeX and not Biber, but with BibTeX not all features of `biblatex` are available. It is recommended you switch to `backend=biber,` and run Biber instead of BibTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: The other messages are unrelated: Most come from multiply defined labels, which suggest you used the same label `fig:Label1` for different figures. Of course that does not go down well with LaTeX since it cannot know which of the several figures you mean when you now say `\ref{fig:Label1}`. Use each label only once and consider using more semantic names like `fig:cat` and `fig:mouse` instead of numeric labels like `Label1`.

Comment: @moewe I also read about `backend=biber` I just wonder why it comes now and never before. Also the second problem never apperead before and I did not add a new label. I went all all them trough so far I did not find any identical labels. But thanks I will try.

Comment: Well, I can assure you this `biblatex` warning has been implemented in `biblatex` for a long time. If you did not update recently and did not change your `biblatex` settings recently, the warning will have always been there. But it is possible that your editor hid the message from you until now. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for some background on the terminology (and also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: It is possible that labels get messed up somehow, so you may want to try deleting your `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.toc`, `.lof`, `.lot` files and recompiling from scratch (do *not* delete any files ending in `.tex`, `.bib` or graphic files).

Comment: @moewe mmh now all citations are gone and it says `I found no \citation  \bibdata \bibstyle commands`

Comment: Did you change from `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,`? In that case you need to run Biber and not BibTeX (see my comments and links above). If you stuck with `backend=bibtex,` keep in mind that you first need to run LaTeX (and the run should finish without errors) before you can run BibTeX. The LaTeX run needs to write the necessary auxiliary files for BibTeX.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot I forget to change it to biberin TexStudio. There are still bad boxes remaining, but I think they are unrelated to the original problem.